# Как применить различные агрегирующие функции к разным столбцам DataFrame после группировки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня DataFrame

```
 col1  col2  col3     col4  col5   col6  col7
 0     Sem   01.2017   2     4     Noo    RX
 1     Kola  01.2017   3     4     Foo    RX
 2     Kety  02.2017   4     3     Roo    RX
 3     Pyti  01.2017   5     5     Kaa    RX
 4     Pyti  02.2017   3     1     Joo    RX
 5     Kola  03.2017   8     3     PPP    RX
 6     Café  01.2017   1     1     Cf     RX
 7     Kety  02.2017   2     1     T      RX
```

Я сделала `groupby()` по двум полям col2, col3 и нашла сумму по полю col4:

```
df.groupby(['col2', 'col3'])['col4'].sum()
```

Получилось:

```
  col2    col3    col4
  Kola   01.2017   3
         03.2017   8
  Kety   02.2017   6
  Pyti   01.2017   5
         02.2017   3
  Sem    01.2017   2
  Café   01.2017   1
```

Но к этой же группировке мне нужно добавить третий столбец `['col5'].unique()`

Итоговый результат должен выглядеть вот так:

```
  col2     col3    col4   col5
  Kola    01.2017   3      4 
          03.2017   8      3
  Kety    02.2017   6      [3,1]
  Pyti    01.2017   5      5
          02.2017   3      1
  Sem     01.2017   2      4
  Café    01.2017   1      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [df.groupby(...).agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [183]: df.groupby(['col2', 'col3']).agg({'col4':'sum', 'col5':'unique'})
Out[183]:
             col4    col5
col2 col3
Café 1.2017     1     [1]
Kety 2.2017     6  [3, 1]
Kola 1.2017     3     [4]
     3.2017     8     [3]
Pyti 1.2017     5     [5]
     2.2017     3     [1]
Sem  1.2017     2     [4]
```